# difficulty booting ubuntu from usb

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows

Hi I am trying to run ubuntu alongside win8.1 but i am having difficulty getting ubuntu to boot from my USB, I have had no problems with installing ubuntu on my other computers via USB but whenever I try to boot from the USB with my main computer, I get a purple screen with a image at the bottom (sometimes). After that the screen goes black with a purple line down the left hand side and it seems to stop doing anything. I am not sure where to go from here. My pc does not support secure boot either. I am trying to run ubuntu 14.04.1 and this problem has happened on previous versions.

Pc specs:

- intel i5 3570k
- Asrock z77
- windows 8.1 (currently boots of a Samsung SSD)
  -

Comment: Have you checked the checksum of the ISO and the media you put it on against the published value? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good step-by-step guide to dual booting with Win8.1 at http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ which covers most of what I figured out from other sites quite well. However, I still had problems like yours. Two things made it work. One: in addition to disabling uefi I had to disable Fast Start in Windows. Two: I still had issues so I tried another suggestion I found (and I'm sorry I can't give proper credit; it was late and I was tired.) I installed the developmental version of Ubuntu 14.10 for that day and everything worked. Now you can get a Beta 1 version, which in my experiance is very stable. YMMV. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please clean up your answer to make it easier to read?

Answer (score -1):

well make sure the motherboard is compatible of the usb if it use uefi try to use leagacy it that dont work it might be the usb or you did not write the image good enough if this help :D have fun with ubuntu well the motherboard might have bugs well try to use a diffrent gpu or the way i have done and i read about is the ui wont show well if you have a cd drive use a dvd or no cd drive get a external and use that should help get the thing working